# how to make a responsive box using html code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

On my blog posts, I have made boxes that have pictures and texts.
**They look broken on mobile while working completely fine on PC**.

So I am trying to make a box that will look fine both on mobile and PC environment, using html code. but **it seems like 'using px or a percentage does not help'!!** I will give you more detailed explanation of my problem as follows!

## 1st problem: the texts go out of the box on mobile

The problem picture (on mobile) texts going out of the box:

[image]

The box should have looked like this (on PC): a perfect box including texts and a pic[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc5kB.jpg)

[image]

The html code to make this box is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="height:300px; width:400px; border: 5px outset #000000;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 15px #000808;background-color:rgb(249,249,249);">

<html>
 <a href="http://www.yes24.com/24/goods/42487097?scode=029">
 <img src="http://image.yes24.com/momo/TopCate1281/MidCate009/128080813.jpg" 
  height = "300px" align="left"/><br>

<body>
  <strong>디지털 노마드(도유진 저)</strong><br>
  출판 : 남해의봄날<br>
  발매 : 2017.06.10<br>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

**As you can see, the problem is that texts located on the right side of the picture are pushed off to the bottom of the mobile screen. Then texts got mixed, which became unreadable.**

I have used px to program the height and width of the box. I have also used px to write the border of the boxes.

I have tried with %,rem,em, several different methods to make a box on my blog posts, but they still do not work on the mobile environment. How can I code to make them look good on PC and mobile altogether?

## 2nd problem (similar problem): cannot be seen on mobile

The problem picture (on mobile): A picture got cut off on the right end

[image]

The box should have looked like this (on PC): You can see the whole picture

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="width:480px; border: 5px outset #000000; height: 
 auto;box-shadow:7px 7px 20px #000808;background-color:rgb(249,249,249);">

<html>
  <a href="http://aictnews.blogspot.kr/2013/08/blog-post_31.html">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-v9CzVdQnsYw/UibtvHFD18I/AAAAAAAABBI/
   X-rjZWuarII/s1600/bongwon+suh.png" width="480px" align="top"/><br>

<body>
  <p style="width:470px;"><strong>""이제 한우물만 파서는 안 돼"</strong><br></p>
  <p style="width:470px;">"1990년대까지는 넓게 알되 한 분야에 능통한 'T'형"</p>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

Since i used "px" to make a box, the picture in a box got gut off on the right end when it's shown on a mobile screen.

## Any help or advice to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `max-width` instead of `width` then make the width always 100%. With this configuration you will have the desired width on desktop and on mobile it will take the width of the screen.

***A side note*** : your html is not valid as it's not correct to put html and body tag inside div. All you content should go inside the body tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="max-width:480px;width:100%; border: 5px outset #000000; height: 
 auto;box-shadow:7px 7px 20px #000808;background-color:rgb(249,249,249);">

  <html>
  <a href="http://aictnews.blogspot.kr/2013/08/blog-post_31.html">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-v9CzVdQnsYw/UibtvHFD18I/AAAAAAAABBI/
   X-rjZWuarII/s1600/bongwon+suh.png" style="max-width:100%;" align="top" /><br>

    <body>
      <p style="max-width:470px;width:100%;"><strong>""이제 한우물만 파서는 안 돼"</strong><br></p>
      <p style="max-width:470px;width:100%;">"1990년대까지는 넓게 알되 한 분야에 능통한 'T'형"</p>
    </body>

  </html>
</div>
```

A better code with valid html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="max-width:480px;width:100%; border: 5px outset #000000; height: 
 auto;box-shadow:7px 7px 20px #000808;background-color:rgb(249,249,249);">
  <a href="http://aictnews.blogspot.kr/2013/08/blog-post_31.html">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-v9CzVdQnsYw/UibtvHFD18I/AAAAAAAABBI/
   X-rjZWuarII/s1600/bongwon+suh.png" style="max-width:100%;" align="top" /></a>
  <p style="max-width:470px;width:100%;"><strong>""이제 한우물만 파서는 안 돼"</strong><br></p>
  <p style="max-width:470px;width:100%;">"1990년대까지는 넓게 알되 한 분야에 능통한 'T'형"</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer a lot, Termani Afif. But can I ask you one more question?

Comment: When I copied and pasted your html code on two of my blogs, the body part became gone. The blog websites deleted the 'body' part ( the part located before 'a href' part.). **So the blog post does not have the box, showing only picture and text**

Comment: Since both of the blog websites deleted the part, I cannot come up with the solution...your html code works completely well on this stackoverflow website with 'Run code snippet'. So I would really appreciate if you take a look at this problem again.

Comment: **[please click here to see the blog post](http://blog.naver.com/herojinwoo/221154144557)**..I have written an article to show you what my problem is. thank you

Comment: @Jinoo, i think the issue is coming from the whole site and not only this block ... as the whole site is no reponsive

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to your answer. I just slightly changed your code. I changed 'body' to 'div' and it works very well on my blog posts. :D Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you can check out my result on the following link. Please go to the bottm of the blog post where you can see 3 boxes with links.
[the result](http://mysnowbear.tistory.com/5)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is not a proper format. You have to use `div`  inside `body` tag.

**First solution**

If you want to create the column then you can use the `flex`. set `display: flex` to the parent div and set `flex:1` to the child div.

```css
  .parent_div{
   height:auto; 
   width:400px; 
   border: 5px outset #000000;
   box-shadow:5px 5px 15px #000808;
   background-color:rgb(249,249,249);
   
  }
  .parent_div img{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .parent_div a{
   display: flex;

  }
  .first{
   flex: 1;
  }
  .two{
   flex: 1;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width : 685px)  {
  .parent_div{
   width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
   <a href="http://www.yes24.com/24/goods/42487097?scode=029">
     <div class="first">
      <img src="http://image.yes24.com/momo/TopCate1281/MidCate009/128080813.jpg"  align="left"/>
     </div>
     
   <div class="two">
      <strong>디지털 노마드(도유진 저)</strong><br>
      출판 : 남해의봄날<br>
      발매 : 2017.06.10<br>
   </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Second solution**

Create a parent div and set the `width:480px` and set `width:100%` to the image. it will display perfectly on the desktop and laptop.

For the mobile device, you have to use the `@media query`

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 685px)  {
        .parent_div{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Set 100% width to the parend div in the media query.it will work perfectly.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
 .parent_div{
   width:480px;
   border: 5px outset #000000; 
   height: auto;
   box-shadow:7px 7px 20px #000808;
   background-color:rgb(249,249,249);
 }
 .parent_div img{
  width: 100%;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width : 685px)  {
  .parent_div{
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
   <a href="http://aictnews.blogspot.kr/2013/08/blog-post_31.html">
   <img src="http://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg"  align="top"/><br>
   <p><strong>klajldjskldjlksd</strong><br></p>
   <p>'ask;ldksldkl;sk;ldas;l</p>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Narendra Verma. But I would really appreciate it if you help me out on this html problem again.

Comment: I have used your '1st solution' on my blog post. **However, the post shows some codes that I have copied and pasted (such as .parent_div) on a post itself and the image got re-resized to a super big one.**

Comment: Since I have experimented with two blog websites, I do not think the websites are backfiring. What I have done is to copy and pasted your codes into the blog posts' html editor mode.

Comment: You can check out how it's not working on the following link. **[Click here : the blog post having the problem](http://blog.naver.com/herojinwoo/221154164032)**.. I would really appreciate it if you help me out once again on this issue.

Comment: @Jinoo, I think there is one space in the img tag. you have to use style .parent_div img also, check the img tag in the HTML code

Comment: @Jinoo, have you checked that?

Comment: I appreciate your answers a lot, Narendra Verma. I think the reason that I had hard time solving my problem was limited access to CSS files and my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Since I used the blogs supported by portal websites, I have only limited access to CSS files. Furthermore, I am making use of  existing layouts made by other creators, so I do not know much about the html and CSS of those layout files. As such, I cannot make much changes to these, using your codes on CSS and html:'(

Comment: So I just made a small change to the code thanks to your input :

Comment: <div style="max-width:450px; width:100%; border: 5px outset #000000; height: auto;box-shadow:7px 7px 20px #000808;background-color:rgb(249,249,249);">
    <a href="website address">
    <img src="image address" style="max-width:100%;" align="top">
  <p style="max-width:450px;width:99%;"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt;">
   abcedfg</span></strong></p>
<p style="max-width:450px;width:99%;"><span style="font-size: 11pt;"> qwerty</span></p></div>

Comment: It works well on my blog :D Thank you for your precious input!

Comment: you can check out my result on the following link. Please go to the bottm of the blog post where you can see 3 boxes with links.
[the result](http://mysnowbear.tistory.com/5)

Comment: I actually did upvote your answer. It's just that I have less than 15 scores, so my upvote is not publicly shown. :( Sorry. but my upvote is recorded on the computer according to the pop-up screen.